# Get the list of custom jQuery plugin functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to access the list of all possible functions accessible from a jQuery selector.

Say I created:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {};
```

I'd like to have the list of all those functions (including the native ones or not, depending on what's possible).

I expected `jQuery.fn` to work but it always returns a *kind of* empty array ...

```
> $.fn
[]
```

I can't believe I can't do that?

Thanks

Comment: hv u tried with $.fn. cuz console.log($.fn) gives list of all functions and properties attached to that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery doesn't use inheritance with `fn` and only uses enumerable properties on it, you can use `Object.keys` to get the full list:

```
var methods = Object.keys(jQuery.fn);
```

Of course, some plugin developer may have chosen to use `defineProperty` and make their plugin function non-enumerable; if so, we have to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```
var methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jQuery.fn);
```

---

> I expected jQuery.fn to work but it always returns a kind of empty array ...
>
> ```
> $.fn
> []
> ```

If you just want this information in the console, on Chrome that works; you just have to click the arrow next to the `[]`:

[image]

to see the list

[image]